# Python 3 - selenium on xvfb-run- cannot process extension

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension, xvfb

I need to automate tasks to extract information from websites using the uBlock plugin with Chrome driver using the `selenium` module in `Python 3`.
I am running my code remotely without a GUI on the remote machine - for that I am using `xvfb-run` to simulate a desktop environment where Chrome launches with a specific window size.

The remote machine has the following `Debian` operating system:

```
uname -a
Linux mem 4.19.0-10-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.132-1 (2020-07-24) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

These were the steps I took to configure my environment and code on the remote machine:

1 - To configure my environment, I installed this version of Google Chrome:

```
google-chrome --version
Google Chrome 86.0.4240.111
```

2 - Check the versions of `Python 3` and `selenium` I installed:

```
python --version
Python 3.7.3

pip freeze
selenium==3.141.0
```

3 - Check the `xvfb-run` version:

```
apt-cache policy xvfb
2:1.20.4-1+deb10u1
```

4 - With these packages configured, I obtained the `chromedriver_linux64.zip` from this list (the version 86.0.4240.22 below is the most recent one that is the same major version of the installed `google-chrome`):

```
https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=86.0.4240.22/
```

5 - To be able to use the uBlock extension of Chrome, I needed to install an extension that is able to produce a .crx archive file of other installed extensions.
For this, I used CRX Extractor/Downloader:

```
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/crx-extractordownloader/ajkhmmldknmfjnmeedkbkkojgobmljda
```

6 - After using that extension, I got my `ublock.crx` file to test.

I managed to use the binary in `chromedriver_linux64.zip` without the extension to launch a Chrome instance and do some basic crawling.
But when I tried to use `ublock.crx` in my code, I got an exception.

The code was this:

This is the exception produced:

```
ublock.crx error
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not 
created: cannot process extension #1
from unknown error: cannot unzip
```

I am launching it from my program like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_extension(ublock_crx_file_path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path, options=option)
```

I have made sure the path of `ublock_crx_file_path` is valid and points to the file I obtained from Chrome.

Hopefully someone can shed light on this?

Comment: And it works on you "non-remote" machine?

Comment: The "non-remote" is Ubuntu with gnome. Using this configuration, I was able to run with the ublock.crx file on the "non-remote" machine. On the remote, I can launch the driver without the extension, but when I include it the error occurs. That is why I added all that information of operating system and program versions.